# how to prevent memory leak in javascript

Tags: node.js, memory, garbage-collection

i stuck into memory leak in js problems.

**Javascript:**

```
var index = 0;
function leak() {
    console.log(index);
    index++;
    setTimeout(leak, 0);
}
leak();
```

here is my test codes, and i use instruments.app to detect memory use of it,
and the memory is going up very fast.

i am doubt that there seems no variables occupy the memory.

why?

any thought is appreciate.

Comment: So what's your production code? maybe only the portion that matter. It doesn't make sense fixing the code intended to cause problem.

Comment: the production code causes the same problem. and i just wane to figure out how to release memory use in these code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code creates a set of closures. This prevents the release of memory. In your example the memory will be released after the completion of all timeouts.

This can be seen (after 100 seconds):

```js
var index = 0;
var timeout;
function leak() {
    index++;
    timeout = setTimeout(leak, 0);
}

leak();

setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
}, 100000);

setInterval(function() {
        console.log(process.memoryUsage());
}, 2000);
```

Comment: omg, that is the settimeout object caused the problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: but, the worst word in the world, there is a problem that, if the cleartimeout event occured when the leak is not trigger, the program will shutdown. i just put the cleartimeout event in the leak function, so it will not shutdown.